# Multi-Tenant Application and Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework, multi-tenant

I am building a multi-tenant application with shared database and  shared schema approach. So as per the approach i have "Tenant_Id" column in each of my table. So is there any way to automatically attach a where clause in every query...

Comment: Hi, I have a very similar question here which may be of help : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9587814/entity-framework-for-multi-tenant-architecture-filterings-single-table-by-tena

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can achieve this using a wrapper around your `DbContext`, and override each collection of entities with a where clause.

```
public class WrapperContext : YourDBContext
{

  public override DbSet<YourEntitity> YourEntities
  {
    get
    {
      return base.YourEntities.Where(t => t.Tenant_Id == someId);
    }
    set
    {
       base.YourEntities = value;
    }
  }      
}
```

Comment: What is the best way to get the someId? In my case, a user can have access to multiple accounts/tenants so that means my WHERE clause needs to be filtered. 

I was planning on getting the list of authorized accounts when the user logs into the application and then storing that list to a session variable. 

MVC4, Entity Framework 5.0, SQL Server 2012.