# How to: Multi-tenancy, single table, single schema, Entity Framework, MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, dependency-injection, multi-tenant

I have been looking for a solution to multi-tenancy around EF. I want to use a single table and single schema (Row Isolation with a TenantID on all tables).

I don't really want to wrap EF (as suggested in the answer of this post [Entity Framework for Multi-tenant architecture - filterings single table by tenant ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9587814/entity-framework-for-multi-tenant-architecture-filterings-single-table-by-tena)) as this will make it very difficult to access all the goodies in EF.

After some research I started looking at Dependency Injection and specifically Autofac, but can't seem to get it off the ground (or maybe just don't quite understand IoC as well as I think I do).

Is what I'm trying to do achievable?
Could DI solve my problem?

Answer (score 1):

Dependency Injection has nothing to do with either EF or multi-tenancy. DI is a means to provide dependencies to all the different pieces of code using them. It has nothing to do with databases.

If I misunderstood your intent, please clarify.

Comment: Let me clarify. Basically all I want to do is have a multi-tenant database and be able to perform queries without needing to send some sort of TennantID to every query through Entity Framework. I want the DbContext to know which Tenant I want to query based on the Url hostname.