# ASP MVC EF6 Multi Tenant based on host

Tags: entity-framework, filter, multi-tenant, interceptor

Sorry, another multi tenancy post. I can't find a good solution to site, I have read tons of great posts on multi tenancy for ASP MVC but I still need some good advice.

I have an ASP MVC Entity Framework 6 Code First web application. This app has to work for many different clients using a single database for all of them.

I have an entity for all the clients, and each client can have different hosts.

```
public class Client
{
    public int ClientId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    ...
    public ICollection<ClientHost> Hosts { get; set; }
}

public class ClientHost
{
    public int ClientId { get; set; }
    public Client Client { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

I have added a column "ClientId" to all the entities I need to filter, so I can separate data from different clients.

```
public class SomeEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    ...
    public int ClientId { get; set; }
}
```

First thing I need is, base on the host, retrieve the ClientId to work with.

```
private static int GetClientId()
{
    var currentClient = Convert.ToInt32(HttpRuntime.Cache[CacheClient]);
    if (currentClient != null) return currentClient;

    lock (Synclock)
    {
        using (var dataContext = new MyDataContext())
        {
            var urlHost = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Host;
            currentClient = dataContext.Clients
               .FirstOrDefault(p => p.Hosts.Any(h => h.Name == urlHost));

            if (currentClient == null) return null;

            HttpRuntime.Cache.Insert(CacheClient, currentClient, null, Cache.NoAbsoluteExpiration, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0), CacheItemPriority.Default, null);

            return currentClient;
        }

    }
}
```

QUESTION 1
As you see I get the clientId from DB and store it in cache, so I don't have to call DB every time I need it.
I don't know if there is a better approach to get the client Id or, better, to store it.

EDIT
After investigation I have created a variable in DbCOntext and initialize it in the Startup.cs file.

```
    public class MyDataContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser, CustomRole, int, CustomUserLogin, CustomUserRole, CustomUserClaim>
{
    public static string ClientId { get; set; }

    public MyDataContext() : base("MyDataBase") { }

    public static MyDataContext Create()
    {
        return new myDataContext();
    }
    ....
}
```

In Startup.cs

```
    public partial class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        MyDataContext.ClientId = ClientConfiguration.GetCurrentClientId();

        ConfigureAuth(app);
    }
}
```

QUESTION 2
Once I have the ClientId, I need to add a filter to every query that needs it. Doing this manually can take you to make many errors or forget to do it in some places.

I need a way that the application can add the filter to all queries automatically (only those entities that need it), so I don't have to worry about a client getting other client's data. Also I need to add the ClientId to all the Insert and Update commands.

I have read about filtering and/or use EF Interceptors, but after reading some posts about that I can't figure out how to do it. Need some help here.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT

In order to solve QUESTION 2 I have followed this great post by Xabikos:
http://xabikos.com/2014/11/17/Create-a-multitenant-application-with-Entity-Framework-Code-First-Part-1/

I have changed it a little bit, since I don't use Users to get the current tenant and instead I use the host. This is part of the program I don't know yet how I'm going to solve but, assuming I already have the ClientId I can add filters to all the queries without realizing that is happening:

I have replaced all the user logic:

```
    private static void SetTenantParameterValue(DbCommand command)
    {
        if (MyDataContext.ClientId == 0) return;

        foreach (DbParameter param in command.Parameters)
        {
            if (param.ParameterName != TenantAwareAttribute.TenantIdFilterParameterName)
                continue;
            param.Value = MyDataContext.ClientId;
        }
    }
```

Same in all the places...

Than I only have to mark the entities that have to filter with TenantAware, indicating the property. In this case I do in my base class and then apply that base class to all the entities I need.

```
[TenantAware("ClientId")]
public abstract class ClientEntity : Entity, IClientEntity
{
    public int ClientId { get; set; }
    public Client Client { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are a couple of things I have done in the past that might help.

**Question 1:**
I am not a big fan of session as the web is supposed to be stateless.  However, it is sometimes necessary.  Your approach is reasonable. You could also use cookies as well.  What I use are Json Web Tokens (JWT) via my authentication provider (Auth0.com). For each request as it is authenticated, I look for this client id. Here is an example. This is MVC 6 as well.  You could do the same type of things w/ cookies.

```
public class Auth0ClaimsTransformer : IClaimsTransformer
    {

        private string _accountId = AdminClaimType.AccountId.DefaultValue;
        private string _clientId = AdminClaimType.ClientId.DefaultValue;
        private string _isActive = AdminClaimType.IsActive.DefaultValue;

        public Task<ClaimsPrincipal> TransformAsync(ClaimsTransformationContext context)
        {
            foreach (var claim in context.Principal.Claims)
            {
                switch (claim.Type)
                {
                    case "accountId":
                        _accountId = claim.Value ?? _accountId;
                        break;
                    case "clientId":
                        _clientId = claim.Value ?? _clientId;
                        break;
                    case "isActive":
                        _isActive = claim.Value ?? _isActive;
                        break;
                }
            }
            ((ClaimsIdentity)context.Principal.Identity)
                .AddClaims(new Claim[]
                {
                    new Claim(AdminClaimType.AccountId.DisplayName, _accountId),
                    new Claim(AdminClaimType.ClientId.DisplayName, _clientId), 
                    new Claim(AdminClaimType.IsActive.DisplayName, _isActive)
                });

            return Task.FromResult(context.Principal);
        }
```

Then in my Startup.cs Configure method I plug in my claims transformer.

```
app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication(options);

    app.UseClaimsTransformation(new ClaimsTransformationOptions
    {
        Transformer = new Auth0ClaimsTransformer()
    });
```

Next I use a base authentication controller that parses out my claims into properties I can use in my controller.

```
[Authorize]
    [Route("api/admin/[controller]")]
    public class BaseAdminController : Controller
    {
        private long _accountId;
        private long _clientId;
        private bool _isActive;

        protected long AccountId
        {
            get
            {
                var claim = GetClaim(AdminClaimType.AccountId);
                if (claim == null)
                    return 0;

                long.TryParse(claim.Value, out _accountId);
                return _accountId;
            }
        }

        public long ClientId
        {
            get
            {
                var claim = GetClaim(AdminClaimType.ClientId);
                if (claim == null)
                    return 0;

                long.TryParse(claim.Value, out _clientId);
                return _clientId;
            }
        }

        public bool IsActive
        {
            get
            {
                var claim = GetClaim(AdminClaimType.IsActive);
                if (claim == null)
                    return false;

                bool.TryParse(claim.Value, out _isActive);
                return _isActive;
            }
        }

        public string Auth0UserId
        {
            get
            {
                var claim = User.Claims.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Type == ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier);
                return claim == null ? string.Empty : claim.Value;
            }
        }

        private Claim GetClaim(AdminClaimType claim)
        {
            return User.Claims.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Type == claim.DisplayName);
        }
```

Finally in my controller it is trivial to extract which tenant is making the call. e.g.

```
public FooController : BaseController
{
 public async Task<IActionResult> Get(int id)
 {
   var foo = await _fooService.GetMultiTenantFoo(ClientId, id);
   return Ok(foo);
 }
}
```

**Question 2:**
One of the ways I have used in the past is create a BaseMultiTenant class.

```
public class BaseMultiTenant
{ 
  public int ClientId {get;set;}

  public virtual Client Client {get;set;}//if you are using EF
}

public class ClientHost : BaseMultiTenant
{
  public string Name {get;set;}
  //etc
}
```

Then simply create an extension method for multi-tenant based entities.  I know this doesn't "do it automatically" but it is an easy way to ensure each multi-tenant entity is being called only by its owner.

```
public static IQueryable<T> WhereMultiTenant<T>(this IQueryable<T> entity, int clientId, Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate)
    where T : BaseMultiTenant
{
    return entity.Where(x => x.ClientId == clientId)
                 .Where(predicate);
}
```

Then when someone calls for their resource you can:

```
var clientHost = _myContext.ClientHosts
                           .WhereMultiTenant(ClientId, 
                              x => x.Name == "foo")
                           .FirstOrDefault();
```

Hope this is helpful.

Also found a [similar example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9587814/entity-framework-for-multi-tenant-architecture-filterings-single-table-by-tena?rq=1) using an interface.

Comment: Thanks @treavorc, please see my resolution on QUESTION 2. About QUESTION 1 I'm still thinking how to do it, since I need to change what I have done since it is not valid if I have different domains in the same instance because it gets the ClientId only on startup.

Comment: Thats why I would reccomend a cookie or JWT type approach. What I left out is that when a user logs in I run a provision service. This service looks to see if user is registered, gets all needed values, and calls my auth server (Auth0). Every time a user makes a request my needed values are in the request.  You could do the same thing w/ cookies. On registration and login create a cookie w/ the client id.  Everytime that user makes a request he MUST have the cookie.  You can then read the cookie contents and use the approach I gave to store them.